# how to convert month name october to 10 in javascript

Tags: javascript

In java script given a month like "October"

how do I **convert to a month to number** format?

Output should be **"10"**, for example.

i have variable called monthName it is giving value as "october",

now how can i convert monthName value as 10

Comment: @ Sam Olesen i tried above code it is not working for me, anyway thank you

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa the answers to the linked question contain all that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this

```
function getMonthName() {
    getMonthName.mnths = getMonthName.mnths ||  ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];
    return (getMonthName.mnths.indexOf(monthName.toLowerCase()) + 1);
}
console.log(getMonthName("October")); // 10
```

Just create an array of months, and add one to the index of the month you're trying to find.

---

This method is lot more efficient than using Date object, as the array of month names is cached and only a look up is done, instead of creating a whole new Date object with unnecessary properties.

This solution is 34% faster than using Date object. This solution DOES NOT allow for terms such as `Oct` and doesn't care for locales, but that isn't asked for, anyway. If you need them, go with `Date` object.

Also, this is among the good solutions as `new Date("October 1").getMonth() + 1` will give you `NaN` in IE10 & 11(The latest of the IEs) and even in the latest Mozilla Firefox.

This solution is cross-browser compatible, is more efficient, and certainly not a bad way of solving the problem.
[**JS Perf**](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-date-obj)

Comment: sorry for unclear i have variable called monthName it is giving value as "october", now how can i convert monthName value as 10

Comment: Please don't do this.  Use a Date object.  This is what it's there for.  It also has the advantage of being case insensitive, understanding the month abbreviations, and being locale aware.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit of a hack, but:

```
var monthName = "October";
var monthNumber = new Date(monthName + " 1").getMonth() + 1;
console.log(monthNumber); // 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's overkill if this is the only work that you will be doing with dates but you could use the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment("October", "MMM").format("M")
```

Output:

```
10
```

Obviously, you can use the name of a variable instead of the string literal "October".